# How to compile a component inside a text?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I use `bootstrap-vue` and I have a text with a `link` to a modal which looks like:

```
'Some Text 2 with <b-link v-b-modal.myModal>a link to modal</b-link>.'
```

This text I put inside `<li></li>`.

Is there any way to inform `Vue` that inside this text I use `b-link` component which must be compiled appropriately?

[My DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/7kx5nqwn40)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

In `<template>`:

```
<details v-for="i in changeLog" :key="i.title">
  <summary>{{ i.title }}</summary>
  <ul>
    <li>{{ i.text }}
      <template v-if="i.linkText">
        <b-link v-b-modal.privacyModal> {{ i.linkText }}</b-link>.
      </template>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

In `<script>`:

```
data() {
  return {
    changeLog: [
      { title: 'Title 2 (with "bootstrap-vue" link)', text: "Some Text 2 with", linkText: "a link to modal" },
      { title: "Title 1", text: "Some Text 1" }
    ]
  };
}
```